# ZF2 - Navigation routing with language

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-navigation, zend-translate

In ZF2 I have two languages English and Chinese. Every route starts with language like:

```
  'about' => array(
      'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
      'options' => array(
           'route'       => '/[:lang]/about',
           'constraints' => array(
                'lang' => '(en|zh)?',
           ),
           'defaults' => array(
               'controller' => 'Application\Controller\About',
               'action'     => 'index',
               'lang'       => 'en',
           ),
       ),
   ),
```

I have already translated label with setTranslator, but I do not know how I can add language parameter to the route. It seems to me like this problem [Translation of URI segments in ZF2](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Translation-of-URI-segments-in-ZF2-td4655520.html)

```
'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'About',
                'route' => 'about',
                'class' => 'top-level',
            ),
         ),
```

Or is there better way how to handle this for example prepend language to every url like this [How to prepend language to every url in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796577/how-to-prepend-language-to-every-url-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is a `params` key in the navigation to supply route parameters. It must contain an array of all values used in the route.

An example, for the route `foo[/:bar]` you can have this navigation configuration:

```
array(
    'label'  => 'Foo',
    'route'  => 'foo-bar',
    'params' => array('bar => 'baz'),
),
```

In your translation case, provide a `params` key called `lang` and than one will be used.

However you probably want to use the route match parameter for the language. If you are on the page from language `zh` then the parameter is automatically `zh`. Then you can use the `use_route_match`.

```
array(
    'label' => 'About',
    'route' => 'about',
    'use_route_match' => true,
),
```